# SQL Like operator with wildcard finding two similar strings - I just want one of them

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like

I have SQL that is searching a column in a table that can contain a lengthy amount of text that represents HTML.

within that text, I want to look for specific links.

my like statement looks like: `'%Controller/action/' + @ID + '%'`

in this example I'm searching for the link Controller/action/12 but it will also pull back Controller/action/125

It's obviously the wildcard at the end that is causing this issue, but because these links can be anywhere in the HTML I need the wildcard. Since I'm looking at anchor tags hrefs I tried `'%Controller/action/' + @ID + '"%'`, but the issue with this is there could be spaces at the end of the href. I can't seem to find SQL that will accomplish what I'm looking for.

Some examples of anchor tags that I'd be searching for.

`<a class="Hyperlink" href="http://test.mydomain.com/Test/account/43  ">`

`<a class="Hyperlink" href="http://test.mydomain.com/Test/account/43">`

Comment: With regular expressions it is a bit easier. You can match after the numbers to non numbers. For example something similar: 'Controller/action/' + @ID + '\D'

Comment: @LajosVeres Thanks that pointed me to the right direction. I ended up using 'Controller/action/' + @ ID + '[^0-9]' and it worked. If you want to submit I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regular expressions it is a bit easier. You can match after the numbers to non numbers. For example something similar:

```
'Controller/action/' + @ID + '\D'
```